# max number of vba bookmarks

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I am currently working on a Word-document I want to use as a template. This template provides a "structure" including many bookmakrs. The template is filled using these bookmarks, e.g.  pictures and texts are inserted at places specified by these bookmarks. It works quite well so far, but when I access my worddocument via excel vba, like:

```
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")                
appWD.Visible = True
appWD.documents.Open ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & targetName
appWD.documents(targetName).Activate
Set mydoc = appWD.ActiveDocument
```

only 256 bookmarks are displayed in mydoc.bookmarks despite the count of 391.

[snipplets of start and end of bookmark list displayed in excel vba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oIsF.png)

In Word I can access all 391 bookmarks without any problems. In Excel VBA all bookmarks listed in  places higher than those 256 are declared unknown. If I try something like the following I get an error stating myBookMark is unknown.

```
mydoc.Goto(what:=-1, which:=1, name:=myBookMark).Select
```

Did anybody experience a similiar problem so far or knows a workaround of how to access bookmarks no. 257 - 391?

thanks a lot

Comment: Is the content inserted at each bookmark unique?

Answer (score 1):

Max # of bookmarks per document: 16,379

Max length of bookmark names: 40 characters

Why are you trying to select bookmarks, given you don't need to do so? For example:

```
With mydoc
  .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="Picture Path & name", _
    LinkToFile:=False, Range:=.Bookmarks("myBookMark").Range
End With
```

Comment: Hi macropod,
thanks for your reply. I also figured out that only 256 bookmarks are displayed in the list in VBA, but the rest is still there (and i can access them, if I omit parameter "which:=1" in goto. 
I need to select them because another subroutine inserts pictures just after the selected range in my document.

Comment: There is no need to select anything to do that. See updated reply.